# java: how to direct download a file?

Tags: java, file, download

Usually I use this code to download a file :

Server:

```
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        long length = file.length();
        out.writeLong(length);
        out.flush();
        while (length > 0) {
            out.writeByte(fin.read());
            out.flush();
            length--;
        }
```

Client:

```
       FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(downloaded);
       long length = in.readLong();
       while (length > 0) {
            Byte next = (Byte) in.readByte();
            fout.write(next);
            length--;
       }
```

And it works, ok, but I was wondering if there was a direct way to download the file from the server.

EDIT:
Now I'm trying to use this cose, but i get a ConnectionException

Server side:

```
        URI uri = file.toURI();
        uri = setHost(uri, getMyIPAddress());
        System.out.println("URI: " + uri);
        out.writeObject(uri);
```

Client side:

```
        File downloaded = new File("downloaded");
        downloaded.createNewFile();
        URI uri = (URI) in.readObject();
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        Files.copy(url.openConnection().getInputStream(),downloaded.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

It's possible to do something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by direct, and how is what you've got not direct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24041297/1393766

Comment: I mean not to have the server read the file. Maybe it is possible to send the URI of the file to the client?

Comment: I want to clarify the context: we have a file on machine A and machine B wants to download it. There is a way to prevent the machine A reads the file to be sent to B?

Comment: I'm trying to use the URI of the file to download it, but it seems to be inaccesible from remote; maybe the NAT block the access? the URI that I use is like this: file://MYIP/C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.jpg . It's possible to do something like this?

Comment: I was reading the smb protocol ... could be useful for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You're using files in you server-client communication, for direct aproach you need to [make use of sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html). You can always include 3rd party libraries for this task, like for example [ApacheHttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/). Hope I helped you a bit.

Comment: The stream that I used already comes from the socket... I was thinking if it is possible to use a URI directly to the file on the server without using the FileInputStream to read it.